# Can I pass named parameters to a fish script?

Tags: named-parameters, fish

I have learnt about [using $argv](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_functions) to access parameter values passed to a fish script (or function). However, this approach requires positional arguments. Is it possible to pass named parameters in an arbitrary order, and extract them based on their name?

For example, the following two calls would be equivalent:

```
favourite_shell best=fish ideological_war=start

favourite_shell ideological_war=start best=fish
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the future and you can now use `argparse`: https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/argparse.html

`argparse` is the outcome of the Github discussion mentioned in the original answer (https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/478), which has now been closed.

Comment: omg the future! how are the flying cars? actually, I bet nothing *really* noteworthy has happened in 8 years

Comment: Yes... absolutely nothing worth mentioning 

Answer (score 2):

Not yet! There's some discussion as part of https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/478 though.